A thread-safe Integer class in C#
After my previous question, I tried to fix the code but still the output is not what I expect. I tried to defined a thread safe integer:
using System;
using System.Threading;

public struct SInt
{
    private int _value;

    public SInt(int initialValue = 0)
    {
        _value = initialValue;
    }

    public int Value => Volatile.Read(ref _value); // Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _value, 0, 0);

    // Add a value
    public int Add(int value) => Interlocked.Add(ref _value, value);

    // Subtract a value
    public int Subtract(int value) => Interlocked.Add(ref _value, -value);

    // Multiply the value
    public int Multiply(int value)
    {
        int initial, computed;
        do
        {
            initial = Value;
            computed = initial * value;
        }
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _value, computed, initial) != initial);

        return computed;
    }

    // Divide the value
    public int Divide(int value)
    {
        if (value == 0)
            throw new DivideByZeroException();

        int initial, computed;
        do
        {
            initial = Value;
            computed = initial / value;
        }
        while (Interlocked.CompareExchange(ref _value, computed, initial) != initial);
        return computed;
    }

    // Increment the value
    public int Increment() => Interlocked.Increment(ref _value);

    // Decrement the value
    public int Decrement() => Interlocked.Decrement(ref _value);

    // Overloaded operators
    public static SInt operator +(SInt a, int b)
    {
        a.Add(b);
        return a;
    }

    public static SInt operator -(SInt a, int b)
    {
        a.Subtract(b);
        return a;
    }

    public static SInt operator *(SInt a, int b)
    {
        a.Multiply(b);
        return a;
    }

    public static SInt operator /(SInt a, int b)
    {
        a.Divide(b);
        return a;
    }

    public static SInt operator ++(SInt a)
    {
        a.Increment();
        return a;
    }

    public static SInt operator --(SInt a)
    {
        a.Decrement();
        return a;
    }

    // Equality operators
    public static bool operator ==(SInt a, SInt b) => a.Value == b.Value;

    public static bool operator !=(SInt a, SInt b) => a.Value != b.Value;

    // Comparison operators
    public static bool operator <(SInt a, SInt b) => a.Value < b.Value;
    public static bool operator <=(SInt a, SInt b) => a.Value <= b.Value;
    public static bool operator >(SInt a, SInt b) => a.Value > b.Value;
    public static bool operator >=(SInt a, SInt b) => a.Value >= b.Value;

    // Implicit conversion from int to SInt
    public static implicit operator SInt(int value) => new SInt(value);

    // Implicit conversion from SInt to int
    public static implicit operator int(SInt sInt) => sInt.Value;

    public override bool Equals(object? obj)
    {
        if (obj is SInt other)
        {
            return this == other;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() => Value.GetHashCode();

    public override string ToString() => Value.ToString();
}

Then I rewrote the program:
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Thread> threads = new List<Thread>();
        SInt s = 0;
        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopwatch.Start();
        for (int i = 0; i <1000; i++)
        {
            var t = new Thread(() =>
            {
                s++;
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            });
            t.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest;
            threads.Add(t);
            t.Start();
        }
        foreach (var t in threads)
            t.Join();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Time: {stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds / 1000.0} Seconds");
        Console.WriteLine(s);
        Console.WriteLine(threads.Count(t => t.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Stopped));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

output in my laptop:
Time: 85.16 Seconds
989
1000

I expect that 989  be 1000.
What's wrong?

Mutable structs are hard to reason about. Mutable structs accessed by multiple threads even more so. Does the code work if you make it a class instead?

@Damien_The_Unbeliever I tested with class instead of struct and the it corrected the output. Be technically SInt should be a value type.

As a general rule, a struct should almost always be readonly struct; there is a use-case for mutable structs in some processing scenarios, but that's pretty rare and needs to be handled very carefully. Basically: "self-inflicted"

@MinimusHeximus a "value" in the sense of n integer: doesn't change. So if SInt should "be a value type", it should be a readonly struct.

By the way if you fix the immediate problem here, you would still have a somewhat dubious kind of "safety". Imagine you want to change an integer via x = 2 * x + 1, on a couple of threads simultaneously while also reading the value from another thread. Starting at 0, we expect to see only integers of the form (1<<k)-1 for any k (1, 3, 7, 15 etc). But that wouldn't happen, because two threads could perform the multiply-by-2, followed by them both adding one, and things go bad. The whole thing needs to be one transaction, making the operations atomic is not enough.

To put what I said another way: there are two competing use-cases for struct in C#, firstly noting that struct is rare to begin with; use case "a" is "custom things that act like values"; use case "b" (even more niche) is "reusable lightweight state machine"; anything in bucket "a" should typically be readonly struct; anything in bucket "b" should be very localized (typically not escaping a single method or type), and is where ref struct becomes useful. Your use-case seems to be "a", in which case concurrency is moot: immutable types don't have concurrency concerns (usually)

Or even simpler: "an integer is already thread-safe; I never need to ask whether 42 is odd vs even right now, because 42 never changes".

In C# a struct is a value type.
Therefore when you return it e.g. in:
public static SInt operator ++(SInt a)
{
    a.Increment();
    return a;   // <-- here a copy is returned
}

You actually return a copy.
If SInt was a class it would behave like you expect, because being a reference type it would return a reference to the current instance.
Note:
As @user555045 commented above even if you solve this specfic problem of using operator++, you will still have problems when it is used in more complex expressions.
